# Parse iOS: PFUser saveInBackgroundWithBlock does not return error when the save does not succeed

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am using anonymous users in parse and if they are not saved, I issue a network call to save them. The code for saving the user is as follows

```
PFUser* current = [PFUser currentUser];
if (!current.objectId) {
    // The user is newly created, don't run any queries for them until they are saved.
    [current saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        // We need a saved user to do stuff.
        if (!succeeded) {
            NSLog(@"Error saving user: %@", error);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Saved anonymous user");
            // ... load data
        }
    }];
    return;
}
```

If I run this in the simulator with no internet connection, the save fails (clearly), but succeeded is true and error is nil, so my code goes into loading data even though the user was not saved. In fact the error gets logged in logs but isn't returned in the callback:

> Error: Error
>   Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to
>   be offline." UserInfo=0x17aa1220
>   {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.parse.com/2/user_signup_or_login,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.parse.com/2/user_signup_or_login,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The Internet connection appears to be offline.,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x1792c880 "The Internet connection appears to be
>   offline."} (Code: 100, Version: 1.2.20)

Is this a bug in the Parse API or am I not using something correctly?

Comment: This was a bug which has now been fixed in the latest release of parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug which has now been fixed in the latest release of parse.

Answer (score 0):

It is not enough to just check the `succeeded` flag, you should also check the `error`.

If you are only going to check one of them, check the error.

The following is the pattern I would use:

```
if (succeeded && !error) {
    // success!
} else {
    // uh oh :(
}
```

Comment: Yes, except in this case error is nil and succeeded is true but the user isn't saved.

Comment: Your error is about an error during either login or signup, but your code above is a save... sounds like the error might be in different code.

Comment: I am saving an anonymous user. That might hit signup or login internally.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the error in the `else` block by using `kPFErrorConnectionFailed` which checks for connection.

Example

```
else { 
       if(error.code == kPFErrorConnectionFailed) 
        {
           // handle error 
        } 

    }
```